# Marking non-sensitive data, to prevent submission from external sources, instead full encryption? (mobile app submitting to a server)

Tags: android, ios, security, server-communication

I want to submit non-sensitive data from a mobile app to a server.
But I don't want external sources to be able to submit data.

I would like some opinions on whether it's enough to mark the requests with hash formula.

For example:

```
MD5(MD5(message)+secretString)
```

The messages will be unique, and there is min of 10 min interval between submissions from single source (if request gets from the same source before this time, it will be rejected).
That's why I think it's not worth the effort to go for full encryption of the requests, but since I have no experience in this area I decided to check with the community.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The approach looks good, few considerations though:

- the `secretString` can be extracted pretty easiely for the app. The only factor here is the motiviation of the attacker.
- consider replacing MD5 with SHA-1. Although there is no fatal vulnerability in MD5, the change is trivial and more secure.
- don't use IP addresses for a "single source" protection. Mobile devices pass through carrier networks and share a relativly small IP block.
- consider adding unique, incrementing number in the request to avoid replay attacks.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be easy to extract if one doesn't know the exact formula and how much "salt" exactly is there (2, 3 secret strings)? My guess is - not, but maybe I am missing something? I am also going to try some request throttling with exponentially increasing penalty interval, so this should pretty much eliminate brute force, I guess. Will use SHA1. The id for the sources will be part of the request body (will not rely on IP). Will add request id to prevent replay.

Comment: Just got what you meant by "single source protection". I don't think I'll have such a thing. The throttle should do it, I guess? Thanks again @buhtum. :)

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to submit data to the server but if you do a hash the data is no longer recoverable by the server. Not only the attacker but even the server will not know what the data is. Going for encryption is the best way to go about this problem if you want to achieve confidentiality. 
As mentioned by another user having a fixed secret string in the app is not doing you any good as it can be recovered easily. You cannot rely on someone not knowing the "formula" reversing an app is easier than people think. So security through obscurity is definitely not the way to go. If you want to use salt use a secure random number generator but then you have the additional task to have the same salt at the server to verify (and the server needs to have the message beforehand).

Comment: I am not sending just a hash. I am including a hash in the request for the purpose of authorization. The data is not in any way secret (hence the "non-sensitive" part), and there will be request throttling which even if one goes through the trouble to get my hash algorithm, will prevent submitting more than couple of requests in reasonable time. Thanks for the opinion.

Comment: Even then having a fixed number of secret string (say N) brings it down to the attacker having 1/N chance of submitting a valid request which might not be the best way of going about it.